# Is MySQL index_length in bytes?

Tags: mysql, indexing

The MySQL documentation defines index_length as "The length of the index file" but doesn't specify the unit.  Is it bytes?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it is bytes. The same holds true for the other lengths in show table status. They are all in bytes:

```
Avg_row_length
Data_length
Max_data_length
Index_length
```