# How do I determine the size of an index in MySQL 5.1?

Tags: mysql

How do I determine the size of an index in MySQL 5.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html) what you need? ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781873/how-to-figure-out-size-of-indexes-in-mysql))

Comment: Yes, it is in bytes. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842086/is-mysql-index-length-in-bytes)

Answer (score 4):

Use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Example : For a table called mydb.mytable, run this query

```
SELECT index_length NDXSIZE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema='mydb' AND table_name='mytable';
```

Answer comes back in bytes. If you want the answer in KB do this:

```
SELECT index_length/POWER(1024,1) NDXSIZE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_schema='mydb' AND table_name='mytable';
```

For MB, use POWER(1024,2)

For GB, use POWER(1024,3)

etc, etc, ...

Comment: @user491757 - welcome to SO. "Signatures" in answers are generally discouraged - people will go look at your profile page if they're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/users/491757/user491757 More details in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq