# How to find out size of indexes in mysql (including primary keys)

Tags: mysql, innodb, indexing

2 common answers are to use  [show_table_status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781873/how-to-figure-out-size-of-indexes-in-mysql) and [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052641/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-index-in-mysql-5-1)

But it seems, both of them don't count primary key's size.

I have tables with millions of records with primary key and no other indexes, and both of methods mentioned above show `Index_length: 0` for that tables. Tables are INNODB.

Comment: Did you understand my answer below? Which part is not clear to you? Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Your primary key is your table. In an InnoDB the primary key contains the actual data thus if the primary key contains the data it is the table.

Think about it for a moment. You get two different types of indexes on an InnoDB table clustered and secondary indexes. The difference is that a clustered index contains the data and a secondary index contains the indexed columns and a pointer to the data. Thus a secondary index does not contain the data but rather the location of where the data is located in the CLUSTERED index.

Normally a primary key is a clustered index. It would be highly inefficient to store both the table with all its values and then a clustered index with all its values. This would effectively double the size of the table.

So when you have a primary key that is on an InnoDB the table size is the size of the primary key. In some database systems you can have a secondary index as a primary key and a separate index as a clustered key, however InnoDB does not allow this.

Go read the following links for more details:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-table-and-index.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

In these links they explain all I have said above in more detail. Simply put you already have the size of the primary key index as it is the size of your table.

Hope that helps.