# MySQL Information_schema index_length

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I checked information about my mysql database, and found, that index_length on tables, that have index only on primary_key column is 0. Index_length of other tables, that have foreign keys and indexes on them has value. Why is it so?

[image]

UPDATE:
Thanks for help, also nice answer given here: [How to find out size of indexes in mysql (including primary keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375289/how-to-find-out-size-of-indexes-in-mysql-including-primary-keys)

Comment: each table has only one primary key (or no primary key) ; the data in the table is physically sorted by the primary key, so it takes 0 extra storage..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table type is InnoDB. InnoDB stores the data in the primary key (index-organized table). So the primary key is already accounted in the DATA_LENGTH.
INDEX_LENGTH means "the size of all secondary indexes".