# Why is the AVG row length 4 times as large as expected?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tree_paths` (
  `child_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sponsor_upline` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `left_leg` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `binary_level` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sponsor_level` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`child_id`,`parent_id`),
  KEY `tree_paths_parent_id_foreign` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tree_paths_child_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`child_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `tree_paths_parent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

An `int(10)` consumes 4 Byte, a `smallint(5)` 2 Byte, a `tinyint(1)` 1 Byte. Thus, one row raw data should be 14 Byte.

I have ~16 Million rows inserted. For some reason the AVG row length is 57 Byte instead of 14 Byte.

[image]

Is it realistic, that the B-tree for the primary tuple key uses 3 times as much storage as the data itself?

In addition, I have read in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30318725/2311074 that

> the primary key is already accounted in the DATA_LENGTH. INDEX_LENGTH means "the size of all secondary indexes".

If that is true, then why is index_length 1/4 of the total size? AS one can see above, I have no secondary keys. Or does it come from the `FOREIGN` keys?

Remarks:

I found similar questions to mine.

One is [Why is InnoDB table size much larger than expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914492/why-is-innodb-table-size-much-larger-than-expected) but it is 10 years old and I don't get it at all. The answer of that question is that a hidden 6-byte column is the reason for the discrepancy there. However, the discrepancy is not 6 but 36. And the user did not use any key, still Index_length is huge. So I have no idea how any of that makes sense, but I guess 10 years ago things were maybe different.

Another answer that I found was at [Average row length higher than possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211377/average-row-length-higher-than-possible). The point in this answer is that InnoDb just allocated more space then it needs. However, when I check `show table status` I see that I have 7.3 MB free left. So it seems I can dismiss this.

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses following an INT declaration is almost meaningless

Comment: @Strawberry its the display width and has no impact on the size, right?

Comment: It has (almost) no impact on anything

Comment: @Strawberry alright, good to know :)

Comment: @scaisEdge yes, but I have no charset field, only intergers, so it should not matter, right?

Comment: If you dump and reload the table into a different table name or database, what is the storage reported then?  my guess is your table may have had deletions whose storage may not have been reclaimed?

Comment: @ysth its actually a fresh table that I have generated from another table (moving from native tree to closure table) so I can guarantee that there were 0 deletions in place, only inserts. But still, I will try what happens. However, it may take some time. I am currently creating the same table without foreig keys, this takes about half an hour before I can tryout to redump it.

Comment: @Strawberry - FYI, 8.0.17 deprecates the number in `INT(10)`.  (`VARCHARs` continue to use such.)

Comment: @RickJames (FYI I knew that)

Comment: @Strawberry - OK.  Then I am talking to everyone else who has not yet encountered it.  Oracle seems to be getting more aggressive at stepping from depreciation to removal.  I hope people will notice before getting burned.  (I have at least one use of `ZEROFILL` in my code; bummer.)

Comment: (Fair enough. But I think it's 'deprecation', although I don't doubt it detrimentally affects value ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons for the avg row size to be high.

- It is an approximation.  (I have found that it is typically 2x-3x high.)  In one extreme case -- one row in the table -- it will claim 16384 bytes per row.  That is one InnoDB block.  The number of rows in the table is *estimated*.  The disk space used for the rows is exact, but see overheads, below.  The avg row size is the quotient of those two.
- Overhead per column -- 1 or 2 bytes
- Overhead per row -- 20-30 bytes -- for handling transactions, finding rows in a block, etc
- Overhead per block -- some number of bytes per 16KB block
- Overhead for thrashing in a BTree -- min is about 1/16 of a block, max is about half the block, the average is about 30% after lots of deletes and/or random inserts.
- Overhead for pre-allocating chunks of disk space (1MB? 8MB?)
- As a table grows from fitting in one block, the layout algorithm shifts, and the percentage of overhead temporarily spikes.
- Deleted rows do not return their space to the OS, so the file size stays constant, thereby increasing the *apparent* row size.
- If you do not have an explicit `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` key that can be promoted to PK, then there is an inaccessibly 6-byte field (per row) for the PK.
- Large `TEXT`/`BLOB` and even `VARCHAR` are stored "off-record".  This complicates the computations a lot.  And it is dependent on which of the 4 `ROW_FORMATs` you are using.  In some cases there is a 20-byte "pointer" for each such cell.
- `FOREIGN KEY` constraints do not add to the space required, except that they *may* force the creation of an index.
- `INDEXes`, other than the `PRIMARY KEY` are no included in the avg_row_length.
- The `PRIMARY KEY` *usually* involves very little overhead in the *data* BTree.  A simple Rule of Thumb is 1% overhead (on top of the column, itself).  This overhead is the non-leaf nodes of the BTree.
- While an InnoDB transaction is busy, any modified rows are held onto in the "history list".  This leads to more overhead.
- (Not totally related).  InnoDB's `COMPRESSED` has issues -- it gives only about 2x compression, unlike typical text compression of 3x.  It costs some RAM because of needing to have both the compressed and uncompressed data in the buffer_pool at the same time (for at least some blocks).

`SHOW TABLE STATUS` and fetching from `information_schema.TABLES` gives the same data.  There are ways to get *some* insight into the depth of the B+Tree for the data and for each table.